# I keep get build error while trying to create github page

Tags: github, jekyll, github-pages

I'm trying to create a github page using jekyll alfolio. I forked the repo from their account and cloned it and made some changes, then i pushed it to my repository and "pages-build-deployment" fails but the "deploy" not and it seems the deploy works well.
don't know whats the problem. it would be great if someone help me with this.

if you guys any more information, let me know.

thanks in advance.

Comment: Please include any errors you have recieved and the code you have changed.

Comment: after i changed the code I forked, I tested it locally and it worked properly, then I pushed it to my repo and I was getting this message:"pages build and deployment by github pages bot, failed". then i change some code that I mentioned in the accepted answer and that fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to this problem.
I added the following part to `.github/workflow/deploy.yml`:

```
- name: Fix permission
  run: |
  chmod a+x bin/*
  git commit -am "add permission"
```

then I deployed it using `bin/deploy --user`.